# NestJS - Swagger - Show all enum values

Tags: typescript, enums, swagger, nestjs

I would like to see all enums value about my dto's property in the body section of swagger UI.

I put this @ApiQuery decorator in my code:

```
@ApiQuery({
  name: 'name',
  enum: ENUM_NAME,
  isArray: true,
})
@Post()
async name(...):Promise<...> {...}
```

But this is used with @Query decorator to let the swagger's filter work. (Find in NestJS Swagger Doc).

So i did not put @Query in my code as you can see, because i want the enum's value in my dto.

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5zTG.png)

But it did not like this solution. it's a workaround.

There is a better way to achieve this result?

Comment: Why would you see your enums in the body section for the GET route ? For a GET route, the query section is used

Comment: @Jboucly You are right, the GET route i wrote was just an example. I asked this question for a POST route. I updated the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not possible in the body section of swagger to do as for the query section, but you can do like this:

```
// app.controller.ts

@Post()
public async name(@Body() dto: NameDto): Promise<void> {}
```

```js
// name.dto.ts

// This is enum for demo
enum Demo {
    DEMO_1 = 'DEMO_1',
    DEMO_2 = 'DEMO_2',
}

export class NameDto {
    @ApiProperty({
        enum: Demo,
        isArray: true,
        example: [Demo.DEMO_1, Demo.DEMO_1],
    })
    public name: Demo[];
}
```

And the result => [image: Swagger]

Or if you don't want dto used

```
// app.controller.ts

@Post()
@ApiBody({
    schema: {
       type: 'object',
         properties: {
            name: {
              type: 'array',
              items: {
                 enum: [Demo.DEMO_1, Demo.DEMO_2],
                 example: [Demo.DEMO_1, Demo.DEMO_2],
              },
            },
        },
    },
})
public async name(@Body() dto: any): Promise<void> {}
```

Comment: The example property of the ApiPropertyOptions solved my problem. I actually improved it by changed from an array of values to Object.value(Demo), so if in the future i add some new values to enum, it will be shown in my swagger UI.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way

```
@ApiProperty({
description: "List of all events",
isArray: true,
enum: TriggerEventType,
example: Object.keys(TriggerEventType),
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is how is resolved this:

```
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ApiProperty({
    enum: DiningAreaType,
    enumName: 'DiningAreaType',
  })
  @IsArray()
  @IsEnum(DiningAreaType, { each: true })
  diningArea: DiningAreaType[];
```